# Is it possible to combine Air and ASP.Net in one app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, air

I would love know if i could combine Air, and ASP.Net in one application and what design strategy would suit this type of application. Please.

Answer (score 1):

Not as such.  ASP is a sever side technology and AIR doesn't have a server it just hands out static pages which can be interacted with using javascript or flash.  You could have AIR call out to a server somewhere which is running ASP.net, that would be fine.

Comment: Can Air stand in the place of JavaScript/JQuery in an application?

Comment: is this entirely true?  I know AIR supports socket programming?  Could you not build a simple ASP parser?